# Repeat a number 3 times for output

Tags: python, numbers, repeat

I need to define a function which repeats a number 3 times. I can only get it to work as a list where the output is [1, 1, 1] if the input is 1. However I need the output to be 111
This is what I have

```
def repeat_number(num):
    if not type(num) is int:
        return None

    list_1 = []
    x = list_1.append(num)
    y = list_1*3

    for i in y:

    return i,i,i

a = 12

print (repeat_number(a))
```

and again I want the output to be 121212

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `str.join` for this, and create a general function:

```
def repeat(something, times, separator):
    return separator.join([str(something) for _ in range(times)])
```

And now use it to create your specific function:

```
def repeat_three_times(something):
    return repeat(something, 3, '')
```

Output:

```
>>> repeat_three_times(1)
'111'
```

Few things to note:

1. I've used `str` to cast the expected integer to a string
2. I've used a list comprehension to create an iterable which is what `str.join` expects
3. I've used `str.join` to create a string which is a concatenation of the strings in the list (see 2).

Here is an example of using the more general function in a different way:

```
>>> repeat(1, 4, ',')
'1,1,1,1'
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without .join?

Comment: Well, it's more extensible if you later decide you want it comma separated and what not, but yes. See @Joran Beasley's answer. I'll edit to let you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
def repeat_number3(a):
    return str(a)*3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeat_num(x):
    return str(x)*3
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output is `[1, 1, 1]` and you were looking for `111`, you can do the following:

```
print (*repeat_number(a), sep='')
```

However, I'd recommend doing the following with your function:

```
def repeat_number(num):
    if type(num) != int: return
    return int(str(num)*3)
```

And then all you have to do is:

```
print (repeat_number(a))
```

as you originally attempted. Plus, this function returns an actual number, which is probably good.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the number as a string and multiply.

```
def repeat(num):
    return str(num)*3

a = 12
print(repeat(a))
```

Comment: Yes; this method is used in previous answers as well. Probably the way to go.